# Getting a YHA discount on Greyhound Australia's website?

Tags: budget, online-resources, australia, greyhound

According to the [discount page](http://www.greyhound.com.au/travel-info/backpacker-membership-discounts) on Greyhound's site:

> Greyhound offers up to 10% off Travel tickets and Passes for customers
>   who hold one of these membership cards.
>
> ```
> ISIC card
>
> YHA card
>
> MAD card
>
> Base Card
> ```

But it's not clear in the booking process how you get this discount.  Is it possible to book WITH the discount on site, or is this only possible on the phone / in a Greyhound office?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [YHA Australia website](http://www.yha.com.au/membership/discounts/national-discounts/) you simply have to choose the Concession rate when booking the ticket online:

> All YHA members get 10% or more off on Greyhound passes and up to 10% off on point to point express tickets. When selecting passengers, choose "Concession" to receive your discount. Present membership card and photo ID at time of travel.

When you book the ticket you can choose the passenger type (standard is ADULT) and that's where you can change to concession.

Comment: Well it was weird because the YHA code didn't fit in the box on the site, so I left the last couple of digits off, and just hoped it'd work out.  They didn't even check it, but I suspect it'd have been fine, and I had a good ride :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the discount, as Drat (above) said, you just show them the card at boarding. However, it's pretty common for places like Greyhound to not check the discount despite them saying that they will check at concession.

Specifically for the ISIC discount...(From http://maphappy.org/2014/12/the-hard-real-truth-about-isic-card-benefits/)

> I bought five separate STA tickets over the course of 2010 to 2012 without an ISIC card. I only got asked for the card maybe once, from Air Canada, I believe it was. My response? I pretended I forgot it at home and asked if I could show my student card instead. The check-in agent waved me through.

Hopefully this helped! :)